# MySQL query select from combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio-2015, combobox

Hi huys I need some help with comboboxes
In the first combo I've imported № of stations from table from MySql.
So In the second combo I need to import the Dates from first selected № of station in the second combo.

In the second combobox2 I write this code.

```
string command1 = "select min(Dat) FROM hyddnev where station=" + comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

But this code not work.

So I need to select the Date when user select in the first combo № of stations for example: 12460 ... to show in the second combo the date from database example: the name of column is Dat ?

My full code is:

```
string MyConString1 = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                "DATABASE=hydrodb;" +
                "UID=root;" +
                "PASSWORD=;";
            MySqlConnection connection1 = new MySqlConnection(MyConString1);
            string command1 = "select min(Dat) FROM hyddnev where station=" + comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command1, connection1);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da1.Fill(dt1);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            {
                string rowz = string.Format("{0}", row.ItemArray[0]);
                comboBox2.Items.Add(rowz);
            }
            connection.Close();
```

Any help ?

Comment: *But this code not work.* What exactly doesn't work? Any problems or errors? What is your required output? Also, if the value is a string, then you'll need `'` around the value.

Comment: No errors, just when you select a preset number of stations in the first combo in the second combo go out dates

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes and open the connection. But the correct approach is to use parameters:

```
string command1 = "select min(Dat) FROM hyddnev where station=@param";
comamand1.Parameters.Add("@param",comboBox1.SelectedItem);
connection1.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(command1, connection1);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
....
```

**EDIT:**

I am talking about sql parameters. See [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What parameter should I put?
In the first combo I have about 300 and more numbers of stations.
And I want when the user chooses the first combo number of the station with a request to the base to show in the second combo dates?